# Extracting a block of fasta sequences with a particular fasta ID

Tags: python, fasta

I'm new to python and tried to go through all the questions here related to what I want but haven't got the answer yet. I want to extract blocks of consecutive fasta sequences in a file which have particular fasta IDs and write the sequences in separate files. The file content is heterogeneous (at some places the fasta IDs are not followed by sequences). The input file is as so:

```
 >ENS00000004062_species1
 >ENS00000004062_species2
 >ENS00000004062_species3
  ATGGGCTTTTCCACAGAGCTTGCAT
 >ENS00000004062_species4
  ATGGGCTTTTCCACAGAGCTTGCAAC
 >ENS00000006504_species2
  CTCTTTGACCCTCCCCATCAGGTTCA
 >ENS00000006504_species3
  CTCTGACCCTCCCCACCAGGTTCAGGG
  CTGGGAGGTGCACTCCAGGGATTC
 >ENS00000006504_species4
```

.... plus many other sequences
  and different IDS but the same 
  pattern of species and fasta IDs.

For example, if I want to extract sequences with ENS00000006504, I want their entire fasta descriptions together with the sequences that follows it but when it will recognize a new fasta ID it should stop. I have this code but it is not doing anything meaningful. It recognize the first line which contains the flag ID but it prints everything afterwards.

```
 flag = 'ENSBTAT00000006504'
 with open(file_name) as file:
    for line in file:
       if flag in line:
          lines = file.readlines()
          print(lines)
```

I hope I have made myself clear but I'm open for more clarification if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: I always recommend the third-party Biopython library for reading FASTA files - in particular its SeqIO module: http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO . If you do it yourself, basically you want to go through the file line by line, with a boolean tracking whether or not you're in an interesting record. Accumulate the sequences until you hit a new description line, and retest whether the new description is interesting. But really, just use the library unless your environment won't let you install it.

Comment: Plus, Biopython has great tutorials and documentation

Comment: Thanks will make a follow-up.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, thanks for the details I tried something like it, to create an empty list and append the lines following the first hit subsequently until a line which starts with '>' but does not have an interesting hit is encountered, but I think I didn't follow the principle in a pythonic way appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Bio import SeqIO

input_file = open('file.fasta','r')
output_file = open('result.fasta','a')
for key in SeqIO.parse(input_file, 'fasta'):
    entry_name = key.name
    if key.name in ['ENSBTAT00000006504']: #Here you can list several IDs
        output_file.write(str('>' + (key.id)) + '\n')
        output_file.write(str(key.seq[0:]) + '\n') 
output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Bio import SeqIO

input_file = "your_file.fa"
flag = 'ENSBTAT00000006504'
selected_seqs = list()

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(input_file, 'fasta'):
    if flag in seq_record.name:
        selected_seqs.append(seq_record)

SeqIO.write(selected_seqs, "new_filename.fa", "fasta")
```

This uses more biopython.

[Biopython Tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html)

[Reading sequence files](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec54)

[Writing sequence files](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec74)

Notes:

- this does not select consecutive seqs only/specifically, but the ones which contain the *flag*. (As FASTA files are mor like dictionaries and ordering doesn't have a meaning [[biopyhton doc on reading FASTA as dict]](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec63))
- seq_record can have many attributes like .name, .id, .description etc. check where your flag is located and adapt if necessary.